# how to replace words in ( )

Tags: python, regex

The output of the following python code using regular expressions is ['A_B1_C', 'A_B2_C', 'A_D2_C']. But I would like to get ['(A)_(B)(1)_(C)', '(A)_(B)(2)_(C)', '(A)_(D)(2)_(C)']. How should I change the code?

```
import re
texts = ['A_B1_C', 'A_B2_C', 'A_D2_C']
keyword = '(A)_(B|D)(.*)_(C)'
[(re.search(keyword, text).group()) for text in texts]
```

Comment: With `[(re.sub(r'[^\W_]', r'(\g<0>)', re.search(keyword, text).group())) for text in texts]`?

Comment: Try change your code for this `formatted_texts = ['({})_({})({})_({})'.format(*re.search(keyword, text).groups()) for text in texts]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to search for a regex pattern and add parentheses around the matches.

```py
import re

input_list = ['A_B1_C', 'A_B2_C', 'A_D2_C']
pattern = r'[^_]'

def add_parentheses(match):
    return f'({match.group(0)})'

res = [re.sub(pattern, add_parentheses, input_string) for input_string in input_list]
```

Note that the regex I've provided is based on your input example; it matches any character except underscores (_). This code will yield the expected output. You can find the reference for `re.sub()` method [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 0):

```
# convert the list into string to be able to use re.sub
st = " ".join(['A_B1_C', 'A_B2_C', 'A_D2_C'])
# after doing the subsitutions split the result string back to the list form.
lst = re.sub(r'([A-Z0-9])', r'(\1)', st).split(' ')
# \1 in the replacment string refers to the matched group ([A-Z0-9])

['(A)_(B)(1)_(C)', '(A)_(B)(2)_(C)', '(A)_(D)(2)_(C)']
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: @Itération122442. A valid point.